# How external libraries install for ffmpeg_kit_flutter?

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg

I would like to use the h264 package:
https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter

But it just say: "you need to install a package with x264 inside. ", but how? What is the actual step for it?

Answer (score 0):

from docs

**2.2 Installing Packages**

Installing `ffmpeg_kit_flutter` enables the https package by default. It is possible to install the other packages using the following dependency format.

```
dependencies:
  ffmpeg_kit_flutter_<package name>: 4.5.1
```

eg audio

```
ffmpeg_kit_flutter_audio: 4.5.1-LTS
```

given that x264 is under [package](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit#8-packages)  `https-gpl` , you install it as follows

```
ffmpeg_kit_flutter_https_gpl: 4.5.1-LTS
```

also a quick look into [publishers page](https://pub.dev/publishers/arthenica.com/packages) should make it easier to see exact package name .

Comment: I have added the dependency with the lame package as mentioned, ffmpeg_kit_flutter_lame: 4.5.0 but it shows the package doesn't exist

Comment: @Akhil lame is under audio , you need to install `ffmpeg_kit_flutter_audio`

Comment: thanks, I have tried installing above package, this is how i wrote the command in executing "-i $url -c:v file2.mp3" but still its return code 1

Comment: you need to clearly define a writable path/ where to save file. Also if this helped dont forget to upvote.

Comment: is there any solution where we can convert without saving audio

Comment: none that I'm aware of,If you dont want to save on the audio on user device, you can save in temporary storage, hidden to user and device will delete at its own liking.